# Within a feature spec, how to test that a Devise mailer is called successfully?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise

I have a feature test for user registration. How do I test that Devise confirmation instructions are sent correctly? I don't need to test the content of the email, only that the mailer has been called.

I am sending mails in the background.

```
#user.rb    
def send_devise_notification(notification, *args)
  devise_mailer.send(notification, self, *args).deliver_later
end
```

I have tried a few approaches that work for other mailers, including

```
it "sends the confirmation email" do
  expect(Devise.mailer.deliveries.count).to eq 1
end
```

and

```
it "sends the confirmation email" do
  message_delivery = instance_double(ActionMailer::MessageDelivery)
  expect(Devise::Mailer).to receive(:confirmation_instructions).and_return(message_delivery)
  expect(message_delivery).to receive(:deliver_later)
end
```

none of which are working as expected for Devise messages.

What am I doing wrong?

### Edit

The feature spec looks like this:

```
feature "User signs up"  do
  before :each do
    visit '/'
    click_link 'Sign up'
    fill_in 'user_email', with: valid_attributes[:email]
    fill_in 'user_password', with: valid_attributes[:password]
    fill_in 'user_password_confirmation', with: valid_attributes[:password]
    click_button 'Sign up'
  end
  it "sends the confirmation email" ...

end
```

Comment: In both of the approaches, can you show the code that actually kicks off your spec by calling `send_devise_notification`?

Comment: I am not explicitly calling send_devise_notification in the spec. The test fills in a registration form and clicks submit. Devise registration controller sends the notification. Please see code added to my question

Answer (score 0):

Since you're doing a high level feature spec, I would wager that as a result of clicking the `'Sign up'` button, what you want to confirm is that an email job has been added to the queue.

In order to do that, you may have to slightly change your spec set up:

```
feature "User signs up" do
  before :each do
    visit '/'
    click_link 'Sign up'
    fill_in 'user_email', with: valid_attributes[:email]
    fill_in 'user_password', with: valid_attributes[:password]
    fill_in 'user_password_confirmation', with: valid_attributes[:password]
  end

  it "queues up a confirmation email job" do
    expect { click_button 'Sign up' }.to \
      have_enqueued_job(ActionMailer::DeliveryJob)
  end
end
```

You can have a look at the [`have_enqueued_job` matcher](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/matchers/have-enqueued-job-matcher) for more options if the above one doesn't quite suit your use case.

Comment: thanks @paul, this looks like a promising approach, however I am getting `expected result to have changed by 1, but was changed by 0`. Does Devise add messages to `ActionMailer::Base` or somewhere else? I've tried `Devise::Mailer` and `Devise.mailer` but no success, and I've found no other ideas in the gem source so far. Or could `deliver_later` be causing the problem? Should I be doing something with the job queue?

Comment: @AndyHarvey I completely overlooked the job queuing part of your question, so I've changed my answer to reflect the use case that you're not testing whether an email has been sent, but that a job has been created that will eventually send the email.

Comment: thanks for your patience, I think we're getting closer. I had been trying with `expect { click_button 'Sign up' }.to change { ActiveJob::Base.queue_adapter.enqueued_jobs }.by(1)` for both of these I get `NoMethodError: undefined method 'enqueued_jobs' for ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::SidekiqAdapter:Class`. I guess Sidekiq makes some changes to the way ActiveJob usually works, but the gem docs are not proving very useful so far. Any idea what syntax I should be using here?

Comment: Does the `have_enqueued_job` matcher work for you to spec out what you want?

Comment: @AndyHarvey did you end up getting the spec that you wanted?  If so, and it was different to this answer, would you be able to post what you ended up doing as an answer?