# Devise invitable doesn't create an invitation in test environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise, devise-invitable

I'm using Devise to manage users. It works in development mode, but not in test. In development, calling User.invite! successfully sends an invitation. In test, it fails silently--no errors, just a nil value for all the invitation-related fields, and the mailer count doesn't increment.

Here's what my test looks like (using FactoryGirl and RSpec)

```
require "rails_helper"
describe "with inviting user" do 

    let(:user) { create(:user) }
    before(:each) do

      Devise.mailer.deliveries = []

      User.invite!({email: user.email}, user)
    end

    after(:each) do
        Devise.mailer.deliveries.clear
    end

    it 'should generate invite token' do
        expect(user.invitation_token).to_not be_nil
    end

    it 'should send an email' do

      expect(Devise.mailer.deliveries.count).to eq(1)
    end
end
```

Both tests fail:

```
 1) with inviting user should generate invite token
     Failure/Error: expect(user.invitation_token).to_not be_nil

       expected: not nil
            got: nil
     # ./spec/mailer/mailer_spec.rb:20:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) with inviting user should send an email
     Failure/Error: expect(Devise.mailer.deliveries.count).to eq(1)

       expected: 1
            got: 0

       (compared using ==)
     # ./spec/mailer/mailer_spec.rb:28:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I'm kind of stumped. Any ideas?

Comment: Just FYI I also set config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true in config/environments/test.rb

Comment: I take it you have this as well `config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test`?

Comment: Yes, that's set by default: config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried checking the deliveries of `ActionMailer::Base.deliveries`? I would bet your emails are there.

Comment: That also remains at 0. I was using the Devise.mailer thing because ActionMailer wasn't showing anything, and I saw somewhere else on stack that Devise skips ActionMailer.

Comment: Funny. In my test env, `ActionMailer::Base.deliveries` definitely gets populated with my Devise emails.... I'll take a closer look at my settings. I take it that in your dev environment that the email is actually sending? :-)

Comment: Yes, it's sending--as in, I can send one to my colleague at his work email address and it shows up in his Thunderbird box--from dev.

Comment: @nilatti Are you sending the emails via `Delayed::Job` or another background task? You may need to give some sleep time if that's the case. Also, see this recent question, it seems like it could be a similar problem if your email is being sent via some background task: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36284664/within-a-feature-spec-how-to-test-that-a-devise-mailer-is-called-successfully?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you are creating a new user and then calling `User.invite!({email: user.email}, user)`. However, when `invite!` method gets called, it creates a new user record and you should try to check that user's invitation token. I took a different approach (I know it is not a perfect one) ), but it works fine.

```
before :example do
   Devise.mailer.deliveries = []
end

after :example do
   Devise.mailer.deliveries.clear
end

it 'sends an invitation email' do
   expect { User.invite!({email: 'user@example.com') }.to change { User, :count}.by(1)
   expect(User.last.invitation_token).not_to be_nil
   expect(Devise.mailer.deliveries.count).to eq(1)
end
```

That's it!